# Install project artifacts to specific directory not .m2

Tags: maven

I to install my project artifacts to specific directory rather than the default .m2 directory. How can I do this (where should I edit in the pom.xml file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Maven Deploy Plugin's altDeploymentRepository parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository). It can be given from the command line, so it should not be necessary to edit the POM file. [Here](https://github.com/orfjackal/jumi-scripts/blob/139d801b41c7511d4555ed4498c50f63d82aec9c/src/build/build-release.sh#L38) is an example of using it.

The relevant section is:

```
mvn clean deploy \
--batch-mode \
--errors \
-Psonatype-oss-release \
-Dgpg.keyname="$GPG_KEYNAME" \
-Dgpg.passphrase="" \
-DaltDeploymentRepository="staging::default::file:staging"
```